# What is the preferred way to implement the Add trait efficiently for Vector type

Tags: rust

The `Add` trait is defined as [seen in the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.Add.html).

When implementing it for a Vector, it was required to copy it into the add method to allow syntax like `v1 + v2`. If the `add` implementation is changed to support borrowed references and thus prevent a copy, one has to write `&v1 + &v2` which is undesirable.

**What is the preferred or best performing way of doing this ?**

(In C++, self would be a `const Vector<T>&`, as well as `rhs`, but still allow the desired `v1 + v2` semantics.)

#### The Code

For completeness, an excerpt of the code I am using right now

```
use std::num::Float;
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Copy)]
pub struct Vector<T: Float> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl<T: Float> Add for Vector<T> {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    // Probably it will be optimized to not actually copy self and rhs for each call !
    #[inline(always)]
    fn add(self, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
      Vector {  x: self.x + rhs.x,
                y: self.y + rhs.y, 
                z: self.z + rhs.z }
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn basics() {
    let v32 = Vector { x: 5.0f32, y: 4.0f32, z: 0.0f32 };
    let v32_2 = v32 + v32;
    assert_eq!(v32_2.x, v32.x + v32.x);
    assert_eq!(v32_2.y, v32.y + v32.y);
    assert_eq!(v32_2.z, v32.z + v32.z);
}
```

Comment: Personally I think the compiler should be able to do a better job when using 'owned' values as it can move them around at will. My fear usually is that unnecessary copies are created, but maybe rust can be different in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `Vector` only contains three values implementing `Float` trait (which means that they are either `f64` or `f32`) you shouldn't really bother that they are copied unless you have profiled your program and determined that multiple copies cause performance drop.

If your type was not copyable and required allocations on construction (like big integers and big floats, for example), you could implement all possible combinations of by-value and by-reference invocations:

```
impl Add<YourType> for YourType { ... }
impl<'r> Add<YourType> for &'r YourType { ... }
impl<'a> Add<&'a YourType> for YourType { ... }
impl<'r, 'a> Add<&'a YourType> for &'r YourType { ... }
```

and reuse the allocated storage in implementations which accept at least one argument by value. In that case, however, you *will* need to use `&` operator if you don't want to move your values into the call. Rust prefers explicit over implicit; if you need reference semantics, you have to write it explicitly.

FWIW, you can take a look at [this](http://is.gd/MFdImi) program and especially its assembly output. This piece of assembly, I believe, is responsible for all arithmetic operations:

```
shrq    $11, %r14
cvtsi2sdq   %r14, %xmm0
mulsd   .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0
shrq    $11, %r15
cvtsi2sdq   %r15, %xmm1
mulsd   .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm1
shrq    $11, %rbx
cvtsi2sdq   %rbx, %xmm2
mulsd   .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm2
movaps  %xmm0, %xmm3
addsd   %xmm1, %xmm3
movaps  %xmm1, %xmm4
addsd   %xmm2, %xmm4
movaps  %xmm0, %xmm5
addsd   %xmm2, %xmm5
addsd   %xmm2, %xmm3
addsd   %xmm0, %xmm4
addsd   %xmm1, %xmm5
movsd   %xmm3, 24(%rsp)
movsd   %xmm4, 32(%rsp)
movsd   %xmm5, 40(%rsp)
leaq    (%rsp), %rdi
leaq    24(%rsp), %rsi
callq   _ZN13Vec3$LT$T$GT$9to_string20h7039822990634233867E
```

Looks neat to me - the compiler has inlined all operations very nicely.

Comment: As I thought, Rust types include their 'modifiers', like `mut` or `&`. `Add` is defined as `pub trait Add<RHS = Self> `, so I assumed that the type of Self must always be the same as the type of RHS in all aspects. Maybe it has to do with lifetimes as well ... .

Comment: `SomeType<T=U>` just defines a default type argument, that is, if it is not specified, it is assumed to be this. This allows writing e.g. `T: Add` which translates to `T: Add<T>`.

Comment: Thank you ! I have many eureka moments now that I (attempt) to learn the ins and outs of rust ! Just a few moments ago I have seen code like this and correctly assumed it is a default type. In my case for some reasons, I was confused. Will have to call it a day, as things don't get better anymore ;)

Comment: This answer is referenced in [Trace Quest 5: Episode 03](http://youtu.be/fg63ZcMnXQE).