# Why does my Trait implementation not match?

Tags: rust

**How can I make this code compile ?**

```
trait Pair<'a, A, B> {
    fn first_ref(&'a self) -> &'a A;
    fn second_ref(&'a self) -> &'a B;
};

struct PairOwned<A, B> {
    first: A,
    second: B,
}

// Only implemented for the cases we are interested in ...
impl<'a, A, B> Pair<'a, A, B> for &'a PairOwned<&'a A,&'a B> {
    fn first_ref(&'a self) -> &'a A {
        self.first
    }
    fn second_ref(&'a self) -> &'a B {
        self.second
    }
}

impl<'a, A, B> Pair<'a, A, B> for &'a(&'a A, &'a B) {
    fn first_ref(&'a self) -> &'a A {
        self.0
    }
    fn second_ref(&'a self) -> &'a B {
        self.1
    }
}

fn pair_transformer<'a, I, T>(pairs: I) -> String
    where   T: Pair<'a, &'a Str, &'a Str> + 'a,
            I: Iterator<Item=T> {
    let mut s = String::new();
    for pair in pairs {
        s = s
            + pair.first_ref().as_slice()
            + pair.second_ref().as_slice();
    }
    s
}

pair_transformer([PairOwned { first: "a", second: "b" }].iter());
pair_transformer([("a", "b")].iter());
```

The compiler says:

```
tests/lang.rs:902:5: 902:21 error: the trait `pair_trait_for_iteration::Pair<'_, &core::str::Str, &core::str::Str>` is not implemented for the type `&pair_trait_for_iteration::PairOwned<&str, &str>` [E0277]
 tests/lang.rs:902     pair_transformer([PairOwned { first: "a", second: "b" }].iter());
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tests/lang.rs:903:5: 903:21 error: the trait `pair_trait_for_iteration::Pair<'_, &core::str::Str, &core::str::Str>` is not implemented for the type `&(&str, &str)` [E0277]
tests/lang.rs:903     pair_transformer([("a", "b")].iter());
```

#### Notes

I have the feeling it is somehow related to the various ways to specify what a trait should be implemented for, something I have not fully understood yet.

```
// As stated in the answer at 
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283641/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-implement-the-add-trait-efficiently-for-vector-type
impl Add<YourType> for YourType { ... }
impl<'r> Add<YourType> for &'r YourType { ... }
impl<'a> Add<&'a YourType> for YourType { ... }
impl<'r, 'a> Add<&'a YourType> for &'r YourType { ... }
```

Using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (522d09dfe 2015-02-19) (built 2015-02-19)`

Comment: fyi, there are more lifetime problems in the code too - try to compile without the 2 `pair_transformer` calls. The trait problem may be related to it.

Comment: By the way: The answer to this question effectively helped me to figure out the problem I actually had: https://github.com/servo/rust-url/pull/82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code:

- You probably want to implement your trait directly for your type, as the methods defined by the trait take the trait *by reference* (which is not the case of the `Add` trait in the other post you linked)
- Your use of `OwnedPair { first: "a", second: "b"}` isn't actually owned: your type will be `OwnedPair<&'static str, &'static str>` so I included examples with `String` (which are owned) as I assume that is what you wanted
- The items returned by your iterator are actually references, so you probably want to bind I to `Iterator<Item=&'a T>`

As I tried to be as generic as possible (and for the example to compile with both `OwnedPair<&str,&str>` and `OwnedPair<String,String>`) I used the trait std::borrow::Borrow, which basically means that it is possible to borrow a reference to the type T from the type by which this trait is implemented.

I also needed to use `?Sized` as a bound for most type parameters. This allows to use types which size is not known at compile time, and will be used behind a "fat pointer". More information in [this blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/05/dst-take-5/) (a little bit old)

Here is the full corrected code (runnable in [playpen](http://is.gd/oFpUCO))

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Pair<'a, A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized> {
    fn first_ref(&'a self) -> &'a A;
    fn second_ref(&'a self) -> &'a B;
}

struct PairOwned<A, B> {
    first: A,
    second: B,
}

// Only implemented for the cases we are interested in ...
impl<'a, ARef: ?Sized, BRef: ?Sized, A: Borrow<ARef>, B: Borrow<BRef>> Pair<'a, ARef, BRef> for PairOwned<A,B> {
    fn first_ref(&'a self) -> &'a ARef {
        self.first.borrow()
    }
    fn second_ref(&'a self) -> &'a BRef {
        self.second.borrow()
    }
}

// It should also be possible to be more generic here with Borrow
// But I wanted to leave your original implementation
impl<'a, A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized> Pair<'a, A, B> for (&'a A, &'a B) {
    fn first_ref(&'a self) -> &'a A {
        self.0
    }
    fn second_ref(&'a self) -> &'a B {
        self.1
    }
}

fn pair_transformer<'a, I, T>(pairs: I) -> String
    where   T: Pair<'a, str, str> + 'a,
            I: Iterator<Item=&'a T> {
    let mut s = String::new();
    for pair in pairs {
        s = s
            + pair.first_ref().as_slice()
            + pair.second_ref().as_slice();
    }
    s
}

fn main() {
    pair_transformer([PairOwned { first: "a".to_string(), second: "b".to_string() }].iter());
    pair_transformer([PairOwned { first: "a".to_string(), second: "b" }].iter()); // It is even possible to mix String and &str
    pair_transformer([PairOwned { first: "a", second: "b" }].iter());
    pair_transformer([("a", "b")].iter());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still digesting this ! It's interesting that `?Sized` cannot be in a `where` clause yet ! It's also quite special, such as I have seen no official documentation about it.

Comment: Thanks to your blog-post, I might have understood more of what's going on. However, I am still unable to understand why the compiler is unable to know the size of the types at compile time, which makes `?Sized` (unsized?) necessary in the first place. This basically makes the trait calls 'virtual' (?), counteracting what a generic would usually do for you (?).