# Adding two numbers without cloning both

Tags: rust

```
use std::ops::Add;
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vec3<N>{
    x: N,
    y: N,
    z: N
}
impl<N> Vec3<N>{
    pub fn new(x: N, y: N , z: N) -> Vec3<N>{
        Vec3{x:x,y:y,z:z}
    }
}
impl<N : Clone + Add<Output=N>> Vec3<N>{
    pub fn  add(&mut self,v: &Vec3<N>){
        self.x = self.x.clone() + v.x.clone();
        self.y = self.y.clone() + v.y.clone();
        self.z = self.z.clone() + v.z.clone();
    }
}
impl<N: Add<Output=N>> Add for Vec3<N>{
    type Output = Vec3<N>;
    fn add(self, v: Vec3<N>) -> Vec3<N>{
        Vec3{x: self.x + v.x
            ,y: self.y + v.y 
            ,z: self.z + v.z} 
    }
}
```

This allows me to write.

```
mod vec3;
use vec3::*;
fn main() {
    let mut v1 = Vec3::<f32>::new(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    let v2 = Vec3::<f32>::new(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    v1.add(&v2);
    let v3 = v1 + v2;

    println!("{:?}", v3);
}
```

This `let v3 = v1 + v2;` consumes v1 and v2. But that is probably not always wanted, so I added another add function  with the signature `pub fn  add(&mut self,v: &Vec3<N>)`

My problem is with this code snippet

```
impl<N : Clone + Add<Output=N>> Vec3<N>{
    pub fn  add(&mut self,v: &Vec3<N>){
        self.x = self.x.clone() + v.x.clone();
        self.y = self.y.clone() + v.y.clone();
        self.z = self.z.clone() + v.z.clone();
    }
}
```

I needed to clone the values of both vectors in order to avoid a move. But I really wanted to write it like this

`self.x = self.x + v.x.clone();` or `self.x += v.x.clone();` I don't see why I would have to clone both values.

How could this be done?

Comment: Please consider removing example code that is not directly relevant to your question (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Specifically the implementation of `Add`.

Comment: You may also be interested in [What is the preferred way to implement the Add trait efficiently for Vector type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28283641/155423).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be no available way to overload "+=" operator. However, you can avoid using exclipt "clone" if you replace Clone trait with Copy (however, you can use them together if needed):

```
impl<N: Copy + Add<Output = N>> Vec3<N> {
    pub fn add(&mut self, v: &Vec3<N>){
        self.x = self.x + v.x;
        self.y = self.y + v.y;
        self.z = self.z + v.z;
    }
}
```

Notice how you don't have to call "clone" at all!

This is a direct quote from Rust's documentation:

> ### When should my type be Copy?
>
> Generally speaking, if your type can implement Copy, it should. There's one important thing to consider though: if you think your type may not be able to implement Copy in the future, then it might be prudent to not implement Copy. This is because removing Copy is a breaking change: that second example would fail to compile if we made Foo non-Copy.

You can find more information about Copy trait [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Seems not to be possible at the moment. The reason is a missing += operator overload.

But clone() on primitive types seems to be just a noop so it actually doesn't matter, I guess.